# Openstack, I can ping br-ex but I can't reach internet

Tags: ping, openstack

[Network Configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TQ8NG.png)

Hi! I've followed the guide to install Openstack in DVR mode
(tutorial here: http://docs.openstack.org/kilo/networking-guide/scenario_dvr_ovs.html)

I've a problem: I can ping br-ex but I can't reach internet (I tried ping 8.8.8.8)

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem when I had installed multi node OpenStack in DVR mode on ubuntu virtual machines. Restatring the networking service usually fixed the problem for me. If the problem still persists, try restarting your system.